# Why does git remove an ignored file (but not an un-ignored file) when pulling a commit that untracked both files?

Tags: git, gitignore

Consider the following situation:

1. a remote repository creates and tracks two files
2. the remote repository later on adds one of the two files to .gitignore (that's not correct, I know, but it happened in our organization)
3. a local repository clones the remote one
4. in the local repository, we untrack both files with `git rm --cached`
5. the remote pulls those changes

I would expect the remote to still have both files, and to stop tracking them from now on.

Why does this happen?

Here is a bash script MWE that replicates what I mean

```sh
#! /bin/bash

# 1. Set up remote repository
mkdir remote

cd remote
git init .
touch file_to_remain.txt
touch file_to_remove.txt
touch file_to_ignore_and_remove.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'first commit'
echo "file_to_ignore_and_remove.txt" > .gitignore
git add .
git commit -m 'gitignore ignores a file that is already in the index'

# 2. clone local repo
cd ../
git clone ./remote local

# 3. untrack both files
cd local
git rm --cached file_to_ignore_and_remove.txt
git rm --cached file_to_remove.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'removed two files from index'

# 4. pull changes into remote
cd ../remote
git remote add origin `pwd`/../local
git pull origin master
```

Instead, what happens is that:

- both files are still present in the local repository
- on the remote, the ignored file is deleted while the non-ignored file is still present.

An additional discovery: if I do a `git status` at before the commit in stage 3 (in the MWE), the `file_to_remove.txt` is shown as both deleted and untracked, while `file_to_ignore_and_remove.txt` is shown only as deleted. When I do a `git add .` only the deletion of `file_to_ignore_and_remove.txt` is recorded.

Comment: For the `file_to_remove.txt` I realize now that, in step 3, I am untracking it and then re-adding it just after. Hence it makes sense that it is not removed from the remote.
The mistake is that I am doing `git add` after `git rm --cached`. Instead, I should do `git commit` right away, without adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem starts right in step 1, with this supposition:

> 1. a remote repository creates and tracks two files

A *repository* does not track files (nor not-track files).  A Git repository consists of, mainly, a set of *commits*.  Each commit contains a full and complete snapshot of all of the files that whoever *made* that commit told Git to include *in* that commit.

What this means—before we get into the issue of tracked vs untracked at all—that we can have a commit `a123456` that contains files `f1` and `f2`, another commit `b56789a` that contains files `f2`, `f3`, and `secret`, and a third commit `cbcdef0` that contains files `f3` and `f1`.

After successfully checking out commit `a123456`, you'll find that you have files named `f1` and `f2`, with whatever contents are in the snapshot in commit `a123456`.  After successfully checking out commit `cbcdef0`, you'll find that you have files `f1` and `f3`, with whatever contents are in the snapshot in commit `cbcdef0`.  It doesn't matter what's in commit `b56789a` here because we never checked it out, even though the *repository* has that commit.  We never notice the file named `secret` because we never look inside the *commit* that has that file.

Git works on a commit-by-commit basis.  We pick some commit to work on or with, using `git checkout` or `git switch`.<sup>1</sup>  Because all parts of *any* existing commit are entirely read-only, and the files inside each commit are stored in a special, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format that the *other* programs in your computer can't use, this "pick some commit to work with" step works by *copying the files out of the commit*, into a work area.  The files inside the commit are not visible!  They are private to Git itself.  The files you work with *are* visible, and are ordinary files, but they were merely *copied out of* the files that Git actually uses (which are stored via *Git objects*, kept in a database inside Git).

**What this means is that the files you see and work with, when you use Git, are not actually *in* Git.**  That's important to keep in mind for the rest of this.  Meanwhile, remember that Git's basic "unit of storage", as it were, is the commit.  Each commit holds *every* file that Git knows about for that commit, by definition.  But these files *are* in Git, and are merely going to be copied out when you ask.

---

<sup>1</sup>The new-in-Git-2.23 `git switch` implements the "safe" subset of `git checkout`, with the new-in-Git-2.23 `git restore` implementing the "unsafe" subset.  If you always use Git 2.23 or later, and want to avoid certain tragic accidents, it's a good idea to train yourself to use the two new commands.  The one old `git checkout` command continues to work, though, so if you're already self-trained to use only `git checkout`, you can continue to do that.

---

#### More about commits

Besides the facts that we already described or assumed above—that commits are *numbered* by those big ugly random-looking hash IDs you've seen, and that each commit has a full and complete (but read-only) snapshot of every file that goes *with* that commit, there's one more thing to know about commits: Each one contains some metadata, which, like all parts of a commit, is completely read-only: you can't change it after creating the commit.

The metadata inside a commit includes things like the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  It includes date-and-time-stamps (two, for various reasons).  It includes a log message, in which whoever made the commit should explain *why* they made the commit, though the quality of this explanation is up to the commit author.  Most importantly for Git itself, though, the metadata of any one commit will include a list of *earlier commit* hash IDs.  These are the *parents* of the commit in question.

Most commits have just one parent.  These are ordinary (non-merge) commits.  They *are* the history in a Git repository.  Adding a new commit, or many new commits, to some Git repository, while keeping the existing ones, is how we add history.  We can do this one commit at a time—by making a commit ourselves—or en masse, by fetching many commits from some other Git repository.  The secret that makes all this work has to do with those big ugly hash IDs.  We won't cover that properly here; we'll just say that *every* Git uses the *same* cryptographic hash function to compute the hash IDs, so that all Gits agree that any particular commit gets its particular hash ID.

In any case, Git arranges for each *new* commit to remember the hash ID of its *immediately previous commit*.  This means that ordinary (non-merge) commits form a simple backwards-looking chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, we've replaced each actual hash ID with a single uppercase letter, and drawn commits with the latest one on the right.  We've called its hash ID `H`.  Git can find this commit, by hash ID, because it's stored in the database of all Git objects, indexed by hash IDs.  That lets Git get at the stored snapshot, and also at the metadata.

Note, though, that commit `H`'s metadata includes the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  So Git can find commit `G`, which lets Git get at `G`'s stored snapshot.  By *comparing* the stored snapshots—`G` vs `H`—Git can tell us what *changed* between the two commits.  This is where things will get interesting.

Of course, since `G` is an ordinary commit, with one parent, `G` has `F`'s hash ID stored in its metadata.  That means Git can walk back from `G` to `F` too, and compare the two snapshots.  Meanwhile `F` stores in *its* metadata, *its* parent hash ID, so Git can walk back another step as needed.  This repeats all the way to the very first commit—the beginning of history—where that first commit simply has *no* parent at all, to tell Git: *This is the beginning*.  That's where `git log`, for instance, will stop, having run out of commits.

Ultimately, this is also how *branch names* work.  We won't go into the details here, but each branch name just holds *one* hash ID.  That one hash ID is the ID of the commit that we wish to call the *last* commit in some chain of commits.  Even if there are more commits after this point, that particular marked commit is the end of *this* chain.  Because of this, Git ends up working backwards all the time: it starts with the end, and works back through history to the beginning.

Remember that none of this stuff inside commits can be changed.  *Branch names* can be changed: you can rename a branch if you want, for instance, but more importantly, you can stuff a *different hash ID* into a branch name.  When you do that, the commit that's the end of the chain has changed.  This is how branches grow, or—if needed—shrink: by moving the branch name to new commits that we add, or by moving the branch name backwards, to some historical commit.

#### Git's *index* and your working tree

Now we come to the issue of actually working with a commit.  As we noted before, everything inside a commit—both the snapshot of all files, and the metadata—is read-only.  Nothing can change it, not even Git (because of the hash trick that makes Git work as a distributed system).  But to make use of the files *in* a commit, we definitely need to be able to read them—which we can't when they are in the object-ized and de-duplicated internal Git format—and we almost certainly need to be able to write to them too.

This is why Git copies the files *out* of the commit.  The copies go into a working area, which Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  As we saw earlier, these are the files you can see and work with.  They are literally just ordinary everyday files.  Git does not *control* this work area!  Git does—usually—make it, initially, on `git clone`, but *you* make it, initially, if you use `git init`.  This work area is now *yours* to do with as you see fit.  Just remember that `git checkout` is a request for Git to fill your work area with files, extracted from some commit.

Note that this means that there must necessarily be at least *two* active copies of your various files:

- there is the frozen one in the *current commit*, that Git took out and put in your work-tree for you; and
- there is the one in your work-tree, that you're working on / with.

Git *could* stop here, with a work area full of files, and with commits.  Some other version control systems do that.  But this isn't what Git does.  Instead, Git squeezes, in between its frozen committed copy of each file and your work-tree copy, a *third* copy.  This means that if you have those files `f1` and `f2` in commit `a123456` and that's your current commit, Git will have:

- a frozen copy of each file, `f1` and `f2`, in its commit;
- another "copy" of `f1` and `f2` ready to go into the *next* commit; and
- the usable copy of `f1` and `f2` in your work-tree.

This middle "copy"—in quotes here, because it's in Git's internal format, which *de-duplicates* files, so it initially literally just shares the originals from the commit—of each file lives in an area that Git gives three names.  Git calls this the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  The last name mostly shows up in flags, like `git rm --cached`.

What's special about the index copy of each file is that Git will let you *replace it*.  The copy in the commit can't be replaced, because nothing about any existing commit can be changed.  But the index is merely a *proposed* commit.  It's not actually a commit yet.  So what's in Git's index *can* be changed.

This is what `git add` does.  This is also what `git rm --cached` does: it changes the *proposed next commit*.  Changing a proposed commit doesn't affect any existing commit, so that's OK.  Git achieves this change by doing one of three things:

- replace some existing file: overwrite the index `f1` with a new version;<sup>2</sup>
- add a new-to-the-proposed commit file: create a new index entry for a file we didn't have in the proposed commit; or
- remove a file from the proposed next commit.

All of these changes, then, happen in Git's *index*.  This means that the proposed next commit is always up to date, and when you run `git add` to *make* that commit, Git just has to snapshot whatever is in Git's index.

This leads to the definition of a *tracked file*.  Technically, Git just defines the term *untracked file*, but it's pretty obvious how to invert that.

---

<sup>2</sup>Since the old file version content is *shared*, this doesn't actually overwrite it, but rather just makes a new one, or finds some other existing copy to de-duplicate.  The actual mechanism behind this uses the same object hash ID tricks that Git uses for commits.  Commits always get a *unique* hash ID, because something *about* each commit is always guaranteed to be unique.  (There's a lot of magic behind this, and the date isn't actually required here, but one way Git guarantees this is that every commit gets "now" as a date-and-time stamp.  You'd have to make multiple commits every second for this part to be the same.)  File contents, if they duplicate some earlier saved version, will just wind up using the old version's hash ID, and hence be automatically de-duplicated.

---

#### Tracked vs untracked files

Once you know how Git uses its index, as the proposed next commit, the definition of a tracked or untracked file becomes almost trivial: **A tracked file is one that is in Git's index.**

That's all there is to it, really.  An *untracked* file is a file you have in your working tree right now, that is not in Git's index right now.  Put that file *in* Git's index—with `git add`, for instance—and it becomes a *tracked* file.  Remove it from Git's index—with `git rm --cached`, for instance—and it becomes an *untracked* file.  You can run `git add` or `git rm --cached` whenever you like, so you can convert a file from tracked to untracked, or vice versa, whenever you like.

But there's a big, and rather hairy, wrinkle here.  When you run `git checkout` to pick a commit to *use*, Git will:

1. fill in Git's index from the commit; and then
2. fill in your work-tree from Git's index.

Suppose you're on commit `a123456`, which has files `f1` and `f2`.  You got there in a normal everyday way and you now have files `f1` and `f2` in your working tree.  Git has `f1` and `f2` in its index.  *All three copies of each of these two files match*, so it's quite safe to move from `a123456` to, say, `cbcdef0`.  So you run `git checkout` on a branch name that identifies commit `cbcdef0`, for instance, to switch *to* that commit.

Commit `cbcdef0` says that we should have files named `f1` and `f3`.  Git's *index* currently has `f1` and `f2` in it.  To make Git's index hold `f1` and `f3`, Git must *remove* `f2` from the index.  Because `f2` is a *tracked* file—it's in the index—Git will *also* remove `f2` from your working tree.  Git can put the right copies of `f1` and `f3` in its index and your working tree, and the checkout is finished and file `f2` is *gone*.

But it's not really gone, is it?  It's perfectly safe, in commit `a123456`.  Just `git checkout` that commit and file `f3` will vanish—it exists now and is tracked but shouldn't exist because `a123456` *lacks* file `f3`—and file `f2` will come back, extracted from `a123456`, now in both Git's index and your working tree.

Note that you can, if you like, run `git rm --cached f3` right now, before switching to `a123456`.  That *removes* `f3` from Git's index.  Now `f3` is an *untracked file*.  Now you can `git checkout` commit `a123456`, and Git *won't* remove `f3`, because `f3` is not in Git's index.  The fact that you have a file `f3` lying around in your working tree: well, that's *your* business.  It's not in Git's index, so it's an untracked files: one of yours, that you've left there for whatever purpose: it's not for Git to bother with.

#### Your local and "remote" repositories

But now, in your example, you've thrown another repository-and-work-tree combination into the mix.  You now have your *local* repository, in which you're running `git rm --cached` and `git add` and making new commits.  That's all fine!  But you also have, somewhere—on your own machine, or on some other machine—another Git repository.  That Git repository has *its own* index and *its own* working tree.

If you are on some commit, and remove some file with `git rm --cached`, it's now gone from Git's index, but still in *your* working tree.  You make the new commit, which *lacks* the file, and all is still fine.

But now, over in the other Git repository, you do something that obtains this new commit.  You still have the old commit checked out, and that has some files that are in both Git's index and your working tree here, on this machine in this other repository.  Now you tell Git: *switch to some other commit* and the other commit *lacks* the file.  The file is in Git's index *here*—this index is part of *this* repository—so the file is *tracked* here, so Git *removes the file*, just as it should.

You will always face this problem in other Git repositories that have commits checked out, if you use this kind of `git rm --cached` trick to remove a file from Git's index and make a new commit while keeping the file in *your* working tree.  That's because *their* index and *their* Git are never told to keep the file.  All they see is "old commit has file, new commit lacks file": that's an instruction to *delete the file*.  It's not gone from the *repository*, but it is gone from the *working tree*.

#### About `.gitignore`

The `.gitignore` file is misnamed.  Git will build a new commit from whatever is in Git's index.  That's the proposed next commit.  If a file is *in* Git's index, it is in Git's index, whether or not the name or pattern is in a `.gitignore` file.  Hence this:

> 2. the remote repository later on adds one of the two files to .gitignore (that's not correct, I know, but it happened in our organization)

isn't *immediately harmful.  Later, it can be; it's not exactly *wrong* but I think it's a bad practice myself.

The `.gitignore` file has several functions.  The most important ones are the ones that affect people doing new work.

When you run `git status`, your Git:

1. prints some generally useful stuff, like `on branch xyzzy`;
2. may or may not print something about *files staged for commit;*
3. may or may not print something about *files not staged for commit;* and
4. may or may not print stuff about *untracked files*.

The list of file names printed in step 2 is a result of comparing the *current commit* to the *proposed next commit*.  For each file that is the same, Git says nothing at all.  For each file that is different in any way, Git says that this file is `staged for commit`, along with a status-code letter: `M` for modified (file exists in both `HEAD` commit and index / staging-area), `D` for deleted (file exists in `HEAD` but not in index); `A` for added, and so on.<sup>3</sup>

The list of names printed in step 3 is a result of comparing the *proposed next commit* to your working tree.  That is, Git diffs the files in the index vs the files in your work-tree.  For those that are the same, Git says nothing at all.  For those that are different, Git prints much the same as before, but now calls these `not staged for commit`.  You can run `git add` on these to copy the work-tree version of the file into the index.

What's a bit peculiar here is that instead of saying that some files are `A`dded, Git gathers up all those file names and then shuffles them off into step 4.  These are your *untracked files*.  Git now whines about them, implying that you ought to use `git add` to add them.

In many setups, there will be many untracked files that definitely *shouldn't* be `git add`ed, because they should not be in the next commit.  Adding them puts them into the proposed *next* commit, which means now you have to go take them out (`git rm --cached`) so that they don't actually go into the commit when you do make it.  We'd like to get `git status` to just *shut up* about this.

So, we list these files in `.gitignore`.  That means that instead of `.gitignore`, perhaps this file should be named `.git-do-not-whine-about-these-untracked-files-in-git-status-output`.

But we also have an easy way of `git add`-ing *all* files: we run `git add .` or `git add *` or `git add -A` or whatever.  This tells Git to add *all* files, en masse, in [one swell foop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swell_foop).  But there are files we don't want to be added: those same files we had `git status` shut up about.  So the file should be called `.git-do-not-whine-about-these-untracked-files-in-git-status-output-and-do-not-auto-add-them-when-I-use-an-en-masse-style-git-add-operation`, or something like that.

The files aren't literally *ignored*, because any file that's in Git's index *will* be in the next commit.  So `.gitignore` is clearly the wrong name.  But the right name is way too long and ridiculous to type in: we might as well call this file `.gitignore`.

There's one other thing that `.gitignore` does, though, and it's where listing a *tracked* file—specifically, any file that will *become* a tracked file upon checking out some commit—can be dangerous.  What the `.gitignore` listing does is give Git permission, in some circumstances,<sup>4</sup> to *overwrite or remove* the file, clobbering data that you might not have saved anywhere.  This is why I don't like the situation where you have a file that's tracked, but also matches a `.gitignore` pattern: it sets you up to lose data later by accident.

(This means the full correct name might really be `.git-do-not-whine-about-these-untracked-files-in-git-status-output-and-do-not-auto-add-them-when-I-use-an-en-masse-style-git-add-operation-but-do-feel-free-to-clobber-them`.  That's ... even more ridiculous.)

---

<sup>3</sup>When you're in the middle of a conflicted merge, all of this changes.  The `git status` documentation is being improved for the next release of Git, to try to help make more sense of the status code letters.  I won't go into further detail here though.

<sup>4</sup>For a very long and wide-ranging discussion of this problem, see, e.g., [this thread from the Git mailing list archives](https://public-inbox.org/git/4C6A1C5B.4030304@workspacewhiz.com/T/).  The usual egregious case (wiping out a local configuration) occurs when you `git merge` a commit that has a configuration file in it, that is not in your *current* commit, but *is* present and *is* listed in a `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Hi @torek, thank you, this is exactly the level of detail I was hoping for.
In addition to mistakingly thinking that git tracks files, I had another error. After removing the files from the index _locally_, I was re-`add`ing them. So the non-ignored file was immediatelly readded to the index, while the ignored file fell into the use case of not being considered because of gitignore.

I have one last favour: you say "give Git permission, in some circumstances,4 to overwrite or remove the file" but you don't give more details at the end. Could you please elaborate?

Thanks again!

Comment: @Sharkovsky87: I think the best thing here is to point you to [this very long email discussion stretching over multiple years](https://public-inbox.org/git/4C6A1C5B.4030304@workspacewhiz.com/T/). I totally forgot to put in footnote 4 though! I'll put this into the answer.